# .Net resolving dependency at runtime for return type of method in generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to find the best approach for a logic that is supposed to retrieve data from different sources and combine them into a JSON object.

I was able to make it work by serializing the results of each source and return **strings**.

Here's a quick example of my solution. Consider that `Orders` can be retrieved from one system, and `Users` from another.

```cs
    public interface IProcessor<IData> {
        public string GetData(IData source);
    }

    public interface IData {
        public string Name { get; }
        public string ApiUrl { get; }
    }

    public class OrdersDataProcessor: IProcessor<IData> {
        public string GetData(IData source) {
            //request data from source
            var results = source.ApiUrl;
            var data = new object { };

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        }
    }

    public class UsersDataProcessor : IProcessor<IData> {
        public string GetData(IData source) {
            //request data from source
            var results = source.ApiUrl;
            var data = new object { };

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        }
    }
```

I can then register these processors with something like

```cs
Container.RegisterType<IProcessor<IData>,OrdersDataProcessor>("orders");
Container.RegisterType<IProcessor<IData>,UsersDataProcessor>("users");
```

There could be many sources of data, so I store a configuration in the database for each combination I want. The last step is to create a service, resolve the dependencies and call the `GetData` method.

```cs
    public interface IDataAgreggator {
        public IEnumerable<IData> Sources { get; set; }        
    }

    public class ProcessDataService {
        private readonly IUnityContainer unity;
        public ProcessDataService(IUnityContainer unity) {
            this.unity = unity;
        }

        public void ProcessData(IDataAgreggator agreggator) {
            foreach (var source in agreggator.Sources) {

                var processor = unity.Resolve<IProcessor>(source.Name);

                var data = processor.GetData();

                // combine all data and return
            }

        }
    }
```

The big problem of this strategy is that the `DataProcessors` are returning **strings**, and it makes the results very limited. For instance, I want to create json schemas for each return type of `GetData`. Therefore it would be a lot helpful if there was a way to keep these data processors generic but at the same time with specific types defined in the return type.

I was thinking of something like this

```
    public interface IProcessorWithType<TReturn> {
        public TReturn GetData();
    }

    public class OrderResult { }

    public class OrdersDataProcessorWithType : IProcessorWithType<OrderResult> {
        public OrderResult GetData() {
            //request data from source
            var data = new OrderResult { };

            return data;
        }
    }

    public class UsersResult { }
    public class UsersDataProcessorWithType : IProcessorWithType<UsersResult> {
        public UsersResult GetData() {
            //request data from source
            var data = new UsersResult { };

            return data;
        }
    }
```

I am struggling to find a way to resolve these dependencies at runtime though. **Does anyone have any better idea to solve this problem?**

My last attempt was this, but I would still need provide a return type to resolve the dependency here.

```cs
    public class ResolveTest {
        private readonly IUnityContainer unity;

        public ResolveTest(IUnityContainer unity) {
            this.unity = unity;
        }
        public void Test() {
            var type = typeof(UsersResult);
            var processorType = typeof(IProcessorWithType<>).MakeGenericType(type);

            var registrations = unity.Registrations.Where(r => r.RegisteredType == processorType);

            foreach (var registration in registrations) {
                // this does not work
                var processor = unity.Resolve(processorType, registration.Name) as IProcessorWithType;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `object`? It will probably not *deserialize* without some custom converter, but if you are only serializing it might work.

Comment: I haven't, but ``object `` wouldn't work for this case since I'm trying to define a different return type for each implementation of ``IProcessorWithType``

Comment: Just as a question: You use UserResults as your example type, yet in your Test you use UserData. Any specific reason for that?

Comment: @SMSTJ sorry that was a mistake. Thank you for pointing that out